# Should the scheduled snapshots feature NOT be used with Windows Server persistent disks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Per the documentation on the GCP site:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot

creating regular (non-VSS) snapshots of Windows Server persistent disks require the following steps:

To create a snapshot:

1. Unmount the filesystem
2. Create a snapshot
3. Remount your disk

If one sets up a scheduled snapshot for a Windows Server persistent disk using the GE Disks interface-provided scheduler, are those snapshots at risk of being unreliable / corrupt as the assumption is the above 3 steps are not automated in any way?

Wanted to make use of the scheduler feature...but it doesn't seem like it was meant to be used for Windows Server persistent disks (And there are no Windows Server clarifying notes in the admin interface of the scheduler).

Any feedback would be appreciated!

-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation on scheduling snapshots [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots#vss), it mentions that you should use guest-flush option to enable VSS so that you can generate shadow copies of the snapshots.

Since it says to enable VSS, then I would not suggest using scheduled snapshots in your use case as you are using non-VSS snapshots.